# Should we store activity content on our local database or not?

Tags: getstream-io

Currently I am sending activity content in custom filed and whole activity is stored at getstream. Nothing on my local database.

What is the best? Should be first store the content message at our database and then send activity to getstream or its ok if we don't stroe activity content at our database

Answer (score 1):

In general it is best practice to store any extra data in your local database and *enrich* activities with this data once they are retrieved from the getstream API, this way you can update any data related to an activity. You can have a look at some of the [Getstream integration](http://getstream.io/docs/#introduction) packages which perform this *enrichment* for you

Comment: in your example for larvel in getstream integration i dont want to use item table of database. then how can i get pin unpin.. means how i enrich activity without item model